# Mixed Content error because of a request to adxk.net

Tags: google-chrome, web

I'm developing a small web app (bootstrap + jquery + nginx + api backend) and today I stumped upon a peculiar error in Chrome, on Ubuntu 16.04.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost/data/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://adxk.net/blacklist_tds.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdata%2F&ref=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foverview%2F&country=PL'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

My page serves all content via https and I'm not making this request.
Firefox doesn't seem to do this request.

**What** (the heck) **is adxk.net**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the work of a dodgy Chrome Extension to me. Developers can use the [chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API to intercept web requests from your tabs and redirect them somewhere else. I recommend you take a look at what you have installed at `chrome://extensions/`.

If in doubt, create a new Chrome profile by clicking your name in the top right corner, then 'Switch person', then 'Add person'. This will completely isolate you from any rouge extension/plugin.

Comment: And let this be a lesson to me to check the permissions before I agree to anything. :) 

This was some picture extension that monitored all my traffic.